# How to visualize networkx graph object using plotly (in Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, networkx

In a Jupyter notebook, I have created a networkx graph object based on data stored in a dataframe. I now wish to draw an interactive graph of the network that will reveal node labels when they are hovered over.

I am having trouble getting started with plotly and I cannot seem to find any tutorials that cover the basics of visualizing networkx graph objects using this library. Most tutorials are more advanced and dive immediately into 3D representations.

This is already allows me to visualize the graph in my Jupyter notebook using matplotlib. How can I customize this graph using plotly?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

Gp=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(comments, source='text_y', target='text_x', edge_attr=True, create_using = nx.MultiDiGraph)

#draw graph 
nx.draw(Gp, with_labels=False)
plt.draw()
```

Comment: It would seem it is normal you only find 3D tutorials. See this [reference](https://plot.ly/python/#statistical-charts) to know all your graph possibilites. I can only find this [3D Network Graph](https://plot.ly/python/3d-network-graph/).

Comment: Thank you, I need to figure out a way to extract node coordinates out of my Graph object in order to position them in 3D space. These are stored in a dictionary containing node names and then the positioning (following the selected layout).

Comment: If you define the 3rd dimension as X for everyone (X being any integer), it should appear as 2D.